# 'TypeError: undefined is not a function' when pulling json data from the github api in Angular?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I'm working on a single page Angular application and trying to work on pulling data from the github api which has access to my github data via: https://api.github.com/users/payam10.

I'm getting the error: "TypeError: undefined is not a function"

All I would like to do is just pull out my login username 'payam10' and place it in the h1 html element. See code below

```
<html ng-app="myapp">
<head>
<title>Angular</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div ng-controller="githubController">
    <h1>{{ user.name }}</h1>
 </div>

<script>
    var myapp = angular.module('myapp', []);

    myapp.controller('githubController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {

        $scope.user = {}

        $scope.user.name = '';

        return $http.jsonp
                        .get('http://api.github.com/users/payam10')
                        .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                          // successful data retrieval
                          $scope.user.name = data.login
                        })
                        .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                          // successful data retrieval
                          $scope.user.name = "Sorry, we were unable to retieve your data."
                        })

    }]);

 </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an error in your code :

`$http.jsonp.get('url')...` should be `$http.jsonp('url')...`

And in your callback you should assign `$scope.user = data.data` to get the full object.

Mind the `data.data`, as it seems that GitHub API wraps its json inside another layer when a callback is specified.

With JSONP you also have to define a callback in your url (I thought Angular was doing it automatically, but it didn't) :

`http://api.github.com/users/payam10?callback=JSON_CALLBACK`

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/700rrazu/5/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/700rrazu/ Can you please show me how you would fix it on fiddle? I tried what you said and I'm getting the same error. It's loaded with Angular.

Comment: I see now. Why did you have to do data twice though in 'data.data.login'?

Comment: When you call GitHub API with a callback, it wraps the json inside another layer. Try going to the new url with the callback.

Comment: what do you mean the new url?

Comment: This one http://api.github.com/users/payam10?callback=JSON_CALLBACK in comparison with this one http://api.github.com/users/payam10

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60275/discussion-between-yoannm-and-user3460974).

Comment: I'm using that url just like how you edited it in fiddle, I'm just wondering why I have to use data.data.login, is there a way around this that you can show me on fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that it's a cross domain request. Browsers prevent that for security reasons.

There are a few workarounds. You can look into CORS, JSONP or perhaps a reverse proxy.

Comment: How do you know that and how can I fix it so it works?

Comment: I changed it to $http.jsonp and it works! but I can't access the data I'm just getting {{ user.name }}

Comment: Because you're only assigning `$scope.user.name` in your callback. Try `$scope.user = data` instead. Also it's `$http.jsonp()` not `$http.jsonp.get()`

Comment: I changed $scope.user.name = data.login TO $scope.user = data and I'm still getting undefined. Shouldn't I be able to fetch the data either way?